# Protractor: After completing its task, it Timeouts

Tags: protractor, timeout

I have been trying to automate a case in which i have to create a group of Urls. So after executing the below script all of the groups that are required are added. After completing all of its task , it is throwing timeout error. But the same objects when used in other specs works perfectly.

```
describe('Test for ToolbarExpandField',function(){
   it('Creating a new url group',function(){
      emulator.createNewURLGroup(URLGroupName,URLGroupList);
   })
})



createNewURLGroup:function(URLGroupName,URLGroupList){
    base.click(base.byElement(base.getLocator(emulatorObjects.dropUpBodyOption,['New URL Group'])));
    emulatorObjects.uRLGroupNameField.sendKeys(URLGroupName);
    browser.waitForAngular();
    base.click(emulatorObjects.confirmButton);
    expect(base.byElement(base.byCss("option[value = '"+URLGroupName+"']")).getText()).toEqual(URLGroupName);
    for(var i = 1; i<URLGroupList.length ; i++){
        tsHelper.checkPresence(emulatorObjects.addNewUrlDiv,true);
        base.click(emulatorObjects.addNewUrlDiv);
        emulatorObjects.urlNameField.sendKeys(URLGroupList[i].name);
        emulatorObjects.urlLinkField.sendKeys(URLGroupList[i].link);
        base.click(emulatorObjects.saveUrlDetails);
    }
    tsHelper.checkPresence(emulatorObjects.addNewUrlDiv,false);
    base.click(emulatorObjects.confirmButton);// Errors occur here
}
```

Comment: Can you also add the step definition here. You are not returning any promise or callbacks

Comment: step definition as in what each steps are doing in code?

Comment: your describe and it block i am asking for

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I just added the step definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of testing is to check and test something. So, each test case should have some expectation and it's result. That's why when you used it in some other test cases, it worked, because those test cases must be already having some expectation.

You can add expectation to `Creating a new url group` test case after calling `createNewURLGroup` function or if you don't have anything to check, then you can just add expectation which is always true (Not a good way):

### Example:

```
it('Creating a new url group',function(){
  emulator.createNewURLGroup(URLGroupName,URLGroupList);
  expect(true).toBeTruthy();
})
```

Comment: Ok . I just added the the expectation.  So now the case is expecting something. But it failed with same error timeout .

Comment: @vishalkedia Also, remove `browser.waitForAngular();` because `Protractor automatically applies this command before every WebDriver action.`

Comment: I just removed the non-necessary wait and sleep and still failed